# What code do I need add so that this javascript adds 3 dots at the end of the text automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

When using this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?callback=?",     function(data) {
  if(data[0].text.length > 107)
     $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text.substring(0,107));
  else
         $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text);
 });
});

</script>

<div class='show_tweet'></div>
```

What code do I need add so that it adds 3 dots "..." at the end of the text automatically?

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
 $.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?callback=?",     function(data) {
  if(data[0].text.length > 107)
     $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text.substring(0,107)+'...');
  else
         $(".show_tweet").html(data[0].text);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fill the available space and not actually limit to specifically `107` characters, you can use CSS to do this [in nearly all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow), via the [`text-overflow: ellipsis` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#text-overflow0).